# Pulling BB prices from a CSV list of tickers in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, bloomberg, pdblp

I am new in Python.. I am trying to pull the latest prices using PX_LAST below, which works perfectly using:

```
from xbbg import blp, pipeline
blp.bdp(["AMZN US Equity", "SPY US Equity","KO US Equity"], ["NAME","PX_LAST"])
```

The issue is, I now wish to pull more prices from my csv file, which include 100 different tickers (in first column). How can I add the tickers from the df into above formula?

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop\tickers.csv')
print(df)
```

```
      ID
0  AMZN US Equity
1   SPY US Equity
2    KO US Equity
3   WMT US Equity
4   BLK US Equity
5  GOLD US Equity
6  ...
7  ...
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your ticker column to a list and feed it as the first argument to blp.bdp:

```
from xbbg import blp, pipeline
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop\tickers.csv')
tickers = df['ID'].tolist()
blp.bdp(tickers, ["NAME","PX_LAST"])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please mark my response as the correct answer and kindly upvote if you found my response helpful